# Javascript linked-list problems with deleting

Tags: javascript, linked-list

Been banging my head against this for a while.  I cant figure out why the node will not remove from my linked list.  I have a linked-list that stores images that I go through and render each one.  Problem is they are still being rendered and not removed.  Is there any problems with my code?  My code seems the same for all other type of linked-lists in javascript.

*edit* Adding full code since it might be useful:

```
var object_action_holder = function () {
    this.skill_id =     0;
    this.skill_type =   0;
    this.image_src =    0;
    this.x_pos =        0;
    this.y_pos =        0;
    this.turn_off =     0;
    this._head =        null;
};
object_action_holder.prototype = {

add: function ( skill_id , skill_type , image_src , x_pos , y_pos ) {

    var node = {
        skill_id:skill_id,
        skill_type:skill_type,
        image_src:image_src,
        x_pos:x_pos,
        y_pos:y_pos,
        next:null
    },
    current;

        if (this._head === null) {
            this._head = node;
        } else {
            current = this._head;

            while (current.next) {
                current = current.next;
            }   
            current.next = node;
        }

        this.skill_id = skill_id;
        this.skill_type = skill_type;
        this.image_src = image_src;
        this.x_pos = x_pos;
        this.y_pos = y_pos;

        },

remove_node: function ( skill_id ) {
    var current = this._head, previous;
    if (skill_id != null && current != null ) { 
        while ( current.skill_id != skill_id ) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if ( current.skill_id == skill_id )
            console.log('found the skill_id');
        if (current != null) {
            if ( current.next != null ) {
                previous.next = current.next;
                return current;
            }else {
                previous = null;
                current = null;
                return current;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
},

get_action_holder: function () {
    var current = this._head;

    var object_array = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (current != null) {
        object_array[i] = current;
        i++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return object_array;
},
}
```

*rendering*

```
var action_image = main.action_holder.get_action_holder();
        for(var i = 0; i < action_image.length; i++) {
            main.game_handle.drawImage ( action_image[i].image_src , (  action_image[i].x_pos * 16 )  + main.player_x - ( main.game_x_pos * 16 ) , ( action_image[i].y_pos * 16 ) + main.player_y - ( main.game_y_pos * 16 ) );
            if ( action_image[i].turn_off == true )
                delete main.action_holder.remove_node(action_image[i].skill_id);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you doing linked lists in JS when you can do arrays natively? Also, what do you mean by rendered? I don't see any DOM related stuff in your code? Is there a rendering function somewhere that isn't here?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I am using lls because I am receiving information from a websocket connection and storing the data into lls.  And then rendering data and then removing the data.  Also checking against the ll to other data to make sure its okay to render.  If you have any suggestions that would be better I am all ears.  I am really new to js programing.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Added the full code.  Sorry for wall of text!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (current != null) {
    if (previous) {
        previous.next = current.next;
    }
    if (current.next) {
        current.next.previous = previous;
    }
    if (current == this._head) { // if the first node is removed, reset head to the next node
        this._head = current.next;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Inside `add_node` method:

```
if (this._head === null) {
    this._head = node;
} else {
    current = this._head;

    while (current.next) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    if (current != node) { // avoid circular reference
        current.next = node;
        node.previous = current; // set previous of the new node
    }
}
```

[Test](http://jsfiddle.net/CW3q4/)

Comment: When it tries to remove the first node it doesn't work, but any other node added after that properly deletes.

Comment: Modified some code in `add_node`, but not sure if it fixes it.

Comment: I added it, it did not fix it however.  :(

Comment: Now that should do it. Forgot to reset the list's head if it is removed.

Comment: MAN!  Thank you so much.  I would have NEVER even knew what to do!  :-).  Another question if you could please let me know in a comment, what type of container is best the fastest in javascript?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16343/discussion-between-ohmages-and-onchie)